# Sum one Column A with Column B into Column A

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make it so that if you press a button in Excel, it sums up one value on one column into the other. for example,

Column A, Column B

1 [5]    , [5]

2 [6]    , [10]

I want the final result should be:

Column A, Column B

1 [10]    , [5]

2 [16]    , [10]

```
Sub Button2_Click()
  Dim i As Integer
  i = 1 
  Do While Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
    Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(i, 2).Value
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to loop until last row in a column, here's how you find it (in column A):

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

So putting it in your code it should look like:

```
Sub Button2_Click()
    ' declare ints as Long, as they are of size of Long anyway
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value + Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next
End Sub
```

Besides that I can't see anything wrong with your current code.

Comment: This is probably the problem i was running into - it was taking too long and had errors at the bottom most likely. Thank you kind sir!

Comment: @simsim619 If answer has helped you mark it as accepted (left green checck mark on the left)